# Convert image from png to webp then upload with ftp in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

#### Preface

**Environment**

OS: Ubuntu

PHP: 7.4

Laravel: `^8.12`

---

I'm writing a scraper page for a web app that I'm developing and these are the steps that I'm trying to achieve:

1. Scrape image from the target website.
2. Convert image from `png` to `webp`
3. Upload converted `webp` to my server via FTP.

The core of the program is one line:

`Storage::disk('ftp')->put("/FILE_UPLOAD_LOCATION", file_get_contents("scraped-image.png"));`

This confirmed that my FTP environment was configured correctly.

#### Attempts and Errors

I should just be able to do the following should I not?

```
$image = createimagefromstring(file_get_contents("remote_url.png");
imagepalettetotruecolor($image); // needed for webp
Storage::disk('ftp')->put('remote_desination', imagewebp($image));
```

The answer is no. This does not work as it just creates a "image" file with `1` as the contents of it.

I haven't tried much outside of this, but hopefully someone has an answer or can point me in a new direction.

Comment: Imagewebp function returns a boolean, not the image it self. The boolean true is converted to 1 when you try to save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because [`imagewebp()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagewebp.php) doesn't return the image, but a boolean indicating either it worked or not.

You must create a handle to store the image in memory then use it to store on the ftp:

```
$handle=fopen("php://memory", "rw");

$image = createimagefromstring(file_get_contents("remote_url.png");

imagepalettetotruecolor($image); // needed for webp

imagewebp($image, $handle);

imagedestroy($image); // free up memory

rewind($handle); // not sure if it's necessary

Storage::disk('ftp')->put('remote_desination', $handle);

fclose($handle); // close the handle and free up memory
```